# Seeming discrepancy between two Fourier transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am familiar with both of the following Fourier transformation identities:

$$e^{jw_0t} \leftrightarrow 2\piδ(w-w_0)$$
and

$$x(t)e^{jw_0t} \leftrightarrow  X(w-w_0)$$

However I need to find out why the $2\piδ$ disappears from the frequency domain when the input signal is multiplied by $x(t)$.

Please could anyone elucidate as to why this is?

My existing knowledge on signal processing is inferior to many people on here, please bare that in mind. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Convolution Theorem of the Fourier Transform and the properties of the Dirac Delta under integration can hopefully shed some light for you:

$$\begin{align}F\left\{x(t)e^{j\omega_0t}\right\} &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\left(F\left\{x(t)\right\}*F\left\{e^{j\omega_0t}\right\}\right) \\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\left[X(\omega) *2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0)\right]\\
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega-\tau)\delta(\tau-\omega_0)\space d\tau\\
\\
&= X(\omega-\omega_0)\\
\end{align}$$

Multiplication of two functions in the time domain is a convolution of their spectra in the frequency domain.

Multiplication doesn't make the Dirac Delta function "disappear"; multiplication performs a convolution in the frequency domain.

The Dirac Delta contributes to the final result of the convolution.  Its contribution specifically results in the shift of $x(t)$'s frequency spectrum, $X(\omega)$, to a new origin, $\omega_0$.

**Update**

Convolution is defined as

$$f(\omega) * g(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\omega-\tau)g(\tau) \space d\tau$$

To proceed with this specific situation, just use:

$$f(\omega) = X(\omega)$$

$$g(\omega) = 2\pi\delta(\omega -\omega_0)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, on the third line could you explain why the w is shifted by t for the X component, yet for the dirac component t is shifted by wo?

Comment: I simply applied the definition of convolution.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition  Note that, under the integral, both $\omega$ and $\omega_0$ are constants, with $\tau$ being the independent dummy variable of integration.  With convolution, one of the functions has it's independent axis offset and reversed (i.e. $\omega - \tau$).  I chose to do that with $X(\omega)$ since it was a little easier to follow.